# UITableViewController scroll with extra space (like Notes application)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, scroll

How do I replicate this behavior found in Notes app:

1. You have a `UITableViewController` with items,
2. You can scroll the list down (with lots of items),
3. When you hit the bottom of the list, you can "overscroll" a bit, but the list wont scroll all the way back. There will be some space left under the last item. This space is utilized in Notes to display some layout image.

To demonstrate with photos:
[image: Photo 1]

This is an "unscrolled" list. Its easy to create such using `UITableViewController`. And when you "pull" the list up, default `UITableViewController` just bounces back to this state.

However, Notes allows this:
[image: Photo 2]

eg. After scrolling to leave a bit of space, don't have it bounce all the way back.

How do you replicate such behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the content insets of your tableView like this :

```
[_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0)];
```

Here you will end up with a 100 pixel inset at the bottom of your tableView when scrolling.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift:**

I think the way to do it in Swift is like this.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 100, 0)
```

I know this is an old question but it might benefit someone.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to do it.

Simply (in your ViewDidLoad perhaps) add a blank UIView as a table footer to the UITableView.

Something like this:

```
UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] init];
footer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 100); // The only one that matters here is the height
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer; // tableView is an outlet to the tableView
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift:

```
    let footer:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44))
    tableView.tableFooterView = footer
```

Answer (score 4):

Updating Kirualex response:

Ideal placement: *UITableViewController viewDidLoad*

### Swift 3:

```
// Add 50 extra pixels at bottom of the list when scrolling
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
```